# Deallocate a Ubuntu VM from itself

Tags: azure, ubuntu, cloud, virtual-machine

I am using a Ubuntu 16.04 VM in Azure to run some GPU computation. Typically, I run my experiments at night and I would like to deallocate the VM when the computation is over (to save some money). Is there any command that I can run from the VM I want to deallocate to actually deallocate it? Shall I just use the Azure CLI? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

When your script works successful, you could judge the return value. Then, execute Azure CLI to deallocate your VM.

```
##your script
if [$? -eq 0];then
 az vm deallocate --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM
fi
```

Notes: If you don't use static IP, it will change IP when you deallocate your VM. Also, if you want to start your VM automatically, you could use Azure automation runbook.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you would want to use Azure Cli or Azure Cli 2.0

```
az vm deallocate --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM
```

or with the cli

```
azure vm deallocate -g myResourceGroup -n myVM
```